# Doctype stops javascript scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I need to scroll vertically the image using javascript, it works:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <script defer>
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => { 
      if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
        document.querySelector('body').scrollTo(0,1110)
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.cam.ac.uk/sites/www.cam.ac.uk/files/shorthand/204072/Y4qHbMIuob/assets/tW5uZTUHvH/credit-timothy-soar_160804-forest-133_1440-by-2560-750x1333.jpeg" />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if my page has at the beginning the tag `<!DOCTYPE html>` it stops working.

Tested using Chrome, Edge and Firefox.

Why? How to solve it?

Comment: Put your script in a .js file and load it with a `src` attribute instead of inlining it. Also, you'll want to fix your HTML: your `<div>` has two `</div>`.

Comment: Both options with or without `<!DOCTYPE html>` are scrolling unreliably during my tests. You need to specifically wait for the html and image to load and only after that invoke scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) instead of specifically scrolling the body. The main scrolling element ([`document.scrollingElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement)) may be either the `<body>` or `<html>` element.

```js
window.scrollTo(0, 1110);
```

In standards mode (with `<!doctype html>`), the scrolling element is the `<html>` element, so scrolling `document.body` has no effect. In quirks mode, it is typically the `<body>` element, so your code works in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [MDN explanation of the `defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#defer), you cannot use `defer` for inline scripts, which you're doing:

> Warning: This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.
>
> The defer attribute has no effect on module scripts — they defer by default.

So, put your script in its own js file, and then load that with `<script src="yourfile.js" defer></script>`, and now it'll *actually* load deferred, as intended.

Comment: This isn't the issue, since the OP is checking for `document.readyState` being "complete". `defer` is just ignored.

Comment: It's not "the" issue, but it's certainly something else to fix. They don't need to listen to state changes when using `defer`, which they are, but they need to put the script in a real file for `defer` to do anything.